# The maximum profit

Tags: calculus

If the price of one ticket for a football match is 40 pounds but if the number of sold tickets exceeds 20 tickets , then the price is reduced by one pound for each ticket . Find the number of tickets that must be sold to get the maximum profit given that the number of tickets can not be more than 50 .
My turn : let the number if sold tickets is $x$ Then the profit $p = 39x $
I think i have modeled it in the wrong way because this model has no maximum ?

Comment: When it says "the price is reduced by one pound for each ticket," that seems to indicate that if $22$ tickets are sold, for example, the price goes down to $40-22=18$. If that's an accurate characterization of what's going on, $39x$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: If it just means "the price goes down to $39$ if we sell more than $20$ tickets," then you have to compare $39x$ to $40\times 20$, where the second term is the profit if you only sell $20$ tickets.

Comment: A third option: the price goes down by $1$ pound for each *additional* ticket sold above $20$ units, which I think is the most interesting of the three possible interpretations.